# dpkg-buildpackage: dpkg-source: no upstream tarball found

Tags: 12.04, dpkg, packaging, deb

I'm trying to untar the files and try to create deb package. This is for my testing purpose. My intention for this testing is, I would like to just provide a folder which contains data to install, and a script to be executed after installation.

https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.4.4.tar.gz

I'm getting this error while building package. Any help would be appreciated

```
ubuntu@ip-10-232-39-177:/opt/uat/elasticsearch-1.4.4$ dpkg-buildpackage
dpkg-buildpackage: export CFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export CPPFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
dpkg-buildpackage: export CXXFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export FFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export LDFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro
dpkg-buildpackage: source package elasticsearch
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.4.4-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Ubuntu <ubuntu@unknown>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build elasticsearch-1.4.4
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: debhelper (>= 7.0.50~)
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: Build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting.
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
```

After installing `debhelper` I'm getting this:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-232-39-177:/opt/uat/elasticsearch-1.4.4$ dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
dpkg-buildpackage: export CFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export CPPFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
dpkg-buildpackage: export CXXFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export FFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export LDFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro
dpkg-buildpackage: source package elasticsearch
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.4.4-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Ubuntu <ubuntu@unknown>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build elasticsearch-1.4.4
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
   dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b elasticsearch-1.4.4
dpkg-source: error: can't build with source format '3.0 (quilt)': no upstream tarball found at ../elasticsearch_1.4.4.orig.tar.{bz2,gz,lzma,xz}
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b elasticsearch-1.4.4 gave error exit status 255
```

Comment: Please edit your question adding information about what package are you trying to install and what are you doing to install it.

Comment: I guess the important line here is `Unmet build dependencies: debhelper (>= 7.0.50~)`. Try running `sudo apt-get install debhelper` and try again. This will install the `debhelper` package and its dependencies. Tell me if it worked, then I'll convert this into an answer, please.

Comment: I would suggest the libdevhelp-dev or similar  is missing

Comment: @Byte Commander after installed debhelper I tried, i'm facing this dpkg-source -b elasticsearch-1.4.4
dpkg-source: error: can't build with source format '3.0 (quilt)': no upstream tarball found at ../elasticsearch_1.4.4.orig.tar.{bz2,gz,lzma,xz}
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b elasticsearch-1.4.4 gave error exit status 255

Comment: Please always [edit] your question to provide new information, especially for command outputs, as you can't format it in a readable way inside comments. Thank you!

Comment: @ Byte Commander sure! I edited my question

Comment: It says `no upstream tarball found at ../elasticsearch_1.4.4.orig.tar.{bz2,gz,lzma,xz}`, so it probably needs the file `elasticsearch_1.4.4.tar.gz` you downloaded in the current directory's parent directory (here: `/opt/uat`, I guess) and renamed to what it requires. Copy it there and try running again.

Comment: @Byte Commander I tried, still the same error exists.

Comment: Did you rename it to `elasticsearch_1.4.4.orig.tar` too? I just noticed the additional `.orig` a few minutes ago myself. Not sure if it's the same file or a different one, it has to be at least named differently.

Comment: @Byte Commander no luck . Still the same.

Comment: Then I don't know. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I referred this blog and did the trick.

[solution found from this forum](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=51479)

This command got fix my issue.

`dpkg-buildpackage -b -rfakeroot -us -uc`

Comment: That is build binary only. dpkg-buildpackage: info: binary-only upload (no source included)